# How can I intercept text messages using cocoa

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sms

I intend on writing an app for iOS that would require me to monitor incoming texts from select contacts etc - in short, I need to somehow get the strings from a text message into my app directly. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple **doesn't provides** any SDK (and **doesn't allows** developers) to access on the messages.

You can just access to the screen **New Message** from the app.